# Should we use enum constants in REST API's path-params, query-params or JSON requests?

Tags: java, json, rest, jax-rs

The question is regarding best practices with respect to REST APIs.

Example: I have a get API with a path-param as status.

```
/api/{status}
```

Now, in the code, the status is defined as an enum (Status). There can only be 3 (or some small finite) possible values of status.

```
public enum Status {
    created,
    completed,
    cancelled
}
```

So, should I accept "status" as a string or as Enum type?

```
@Path("/api/{status}")
@GET
public Response get(@PathParam("status") String status) {}
// then I can check if it is a valid status
```

OR

```
@Path("/api/{status}")
@GET
public Response get(@PathParam("status") Status status) {}
// it will throw an exception if it is an invalid status
```

Also, I would like to know the best-practices with respect to query-params and JSON requests as well.

Comment: I tend to prefer Strings over Enums in APIs for exactly this reason; it's often more convenient to perform validation and format a helpful error message at the implementation-level than trying to do it with a filter.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the right way. But then, when we give out API contracts, we explicitly mention what values we are expecting. I'm using Swagger for automatically creating the API documentation. It can easily detect the whitelisted values from the code and prepare the document accordingly if I use Enum type in the request. But if I use string, I'll have to manually edit the API doc to write down the whitelisted values. But I would prefer to do whatever is the standard, instead of what is convenient for me. Isn't there a standard with respect to this?

Comment: Enum types are a better way to document acceptable values.  If you’re maintaining good API documentation that describes acceptable values, String isn’t terrible, but are other developers on your team as meticulous about such documentation?

Comment: @VGR Actually, I'm the only one working on these REST services as I work in a very small team. But still, I need to handout the API contracts to other teams. So, I have to be meticulous about the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Using enums on API, brings better design. Reasons for it are same as why we use them in general. There is compatibility between enums in programming languages that have them, and OpenApi specification https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/enums/ therefore there I see no good argument against them.